# .gitignore doesn't ignore untracked files

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore untracked files shown below, but it keeps showing.
I tried deleting cached files (`git rm --cached CruiserConsole*.*`) but it didn't work.

```
D:\Git\CruiseProtocolScripts [master +8 ~1 -0 !]> git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       CruiserConsole.exe
#       CruiserConsole.exe.config
#       CruiserConsole.pdb
#       CruiserConsole.vshost.exe
#       CruiserConsole.vshost.exe.config
#       CruiserConsole.vshost.exe.manifest
#       LuaInterface.dll
#       lua51.dll
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
D:\Git\CruiseProtocolScripts [master +8 ~0 -0 !]> git rm --cached .\CruiserConsole.*
fatal: pathspec 'CruiserConsole.*' did not match any files
```

Here's my .gitignore file.

```
/CruiserConsole*.*
/*.dll
```

I guess I have improper pattern matching for file names, but I cannot point what's the exact problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried the same filenames and .gitignore as yours. Works on my Linux.

Comment: @KamilDomański I forgot to mention that I'm on Windows with powershell. Thank you for your comment though!

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `/` at the beginning of each line. Your `.gitignore` should look like:

```
CruiserConsole*.*
*.dll
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I want to ignore the files within the root directory, so i need `/` here.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, path slashes on Windows work the other way. Try changing these "/" to "\" or "\\".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried and nothing changed, though.